# Extract package description as string in R

Tags: r, shiny, metadata

How can I extract the description of a package from the package's `DESCRIPTION` file?

I'm interested in getting the text from the `Description:` field and being able to use it in `renderText()` for a Shiny app. `renderText()` just requires a string, so getting it in a string format is my goal (unless someone knows another way to do it).

The reason I'm not just copy-pasting is because I want to update the description in one single place (the `DESCRIPTION` file) and not have to remember to update the description in multiple locations with every new version.

Comment: `read.dcf()` should get you what you need (i.e. `read.dcf(list.files(file.path(.libPaths()[1], "stats"), "DESCRIPTION", full.names=TRUE))[,"Description"]`) also `?packageDescription`

Comment: Ahh I like this packageDescription even more! Feel free to write up as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on hrbrmstr's great suggestion, I checked out the `packageDescription()` function. I also wrapped it in a `gsub` to convert the line breaks to spaces. In the package description, line breaks are required every 80 characters so the `gsub()` removes those line breaks from the string.

```
gsub('\n\\s+', ' ', packageDescription(pkg = 'respirometry', fields = 'Description'))
```